# Symfony CSRF domain and subdomain

Tags: symfony, csrf

I have a problem with Symfony's CSRF protection.

When I log on to the domain toto.com, it works, but when I try to connect to the domain test.toto.com (same server, same code, it's just a redirection to toto.com), I have an error 'CSRF Invalid token'.

Do you know how I can solve this problem? How do you test your applications before you push them on the prod? do you have a sub-domain?

Thank you.

**[edit - 18-04-03]**

Added :

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: xxxx.com
```

in my config_prod.yml file. It's not working

**[edit v2 - 18-04-03 - working]**

```
framework
    trusted_hosts:  ['toto.com', 'test.toto.com']
    session:
        cookie_domain: .toto.com
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/"
        cookie_lifetime: 31536000
        name: totosessionid
```

Look like it's working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set cookie_domain, save_path: and name: in the config (for framework).

Comment: Aren't you trying to use this on a subdomain? Have you tried to set test.toto.com?

Comment: Yes, it's on a subdomain. test.toto.com My login doesn't working

Comment: Sorry. I missed the part about the redirect. Have you tried the cookie_domain: .toto.com option? If it is not working what Symfony version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I put in my config_prod  cookie_domain: .toto.com
Not working too. My symfony version is 3.4. I delete my cookies too.

Comment: Try to set save_path: and name:

Answer (score 0):

To include a domain and its subdomains, you should use this syntax:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .xxxx.com
```

Other syntaxes may cause issues with specific browsers (mostly old IE, as far I remember).